# Does there exist a real differentiable function $‎f:‎\mathbb{R}‎\rightarrow‎\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

(a) ‎‎$‎‎\mathbb{N}‎‎\subseteq D_f‎$;

‎(b) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^\prime(n) = 0$;

(c)  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f(n) - \sum_{k=1}^n f^\prime(k)) = 0$.

Comment: The always vanishing map works.

Comment: $f(x)=\log(x)-\gamma$ works too. There are many examples.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net your username confused me and thought you were linking a url

Comment: @clark The url exists... But my username isn't linked to it, unfortunately!

Comment: Remark: Why do you define $f_n$ and $f_n'$ if you don't use it?

Comment: Please read the comment of @MundronSchmidt. Don't introduce notation that you don't use!

Comment: thank you so much. idok

Comment: ok. You are right, I corrected. mundron schmid

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function $f(x) = 0$ fulfills all of those properties.